# Should I use AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer or WebApplicationInitializer configure Spring 4.0 mvc + Security application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, config

I read examples and can't understand, should I use WebApplicationInitializer or AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer to configure my spring application?

Comment: Presumably you are trying to avoid the use of the ``web.xml`` and move your web app config into annotated java, rather than xml?

Comment: I would agree with jny. The ``AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer`` would be the best place to start as it guides you into adding the basic required functionality from the outset. That said, you could still achieve the same results with ``WebApplicationInitializer`` but you would have to figure out and add the basics yourself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not either/or choice. *AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer* implements *WebApplicationInitializer,* but already provides some functionality so you have to add very little. I suggest you start with  *AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer* and see if it works for you, you can always switch to *WebApplicationInitializer* later.